# Subtract Group Columns in Matrix table in SSRS

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, group-by, ssrs-2008, subtraction

I have a matrix table grouped by WBS and Acc at row level.
Then i have a column group "Table" with Plan & Actuals. What i want to get is (Plan)-(Actuals)

I used the below expression in a outer group column

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Table.Value = "Plan", (Fields!Total.Value),0))-SUM(IIF(Fields!Table.Value = "Actuals", (Fields!Total.Value),0))
```

The total.value is the total of plan and actuals individually.

I am getting an error in the calculated column (Expression)

The Matrix Table[The Matrix Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIWOG.jpg)

[The Dataset and Outputs (expected and current)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd9s2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only ever have two fixed values in your `Table` column then you should be able to do this without the need for custom code.

Something like this...

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Table.Value = "Plan", Fields!Total.Value,0))
 - 
 SUM(IIF(Fields!Table.Value = "Actuals", Fields!Total.Value,0))
```

**UPDATE for clarity**

I have created a report based on your sample data and the above works as expected.

I created a dataset using the following query

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (WBSNumbers varchar(20), [Table] varchar(20), Account Varchar(20), Total float)

INSERT INTO @t 
SELECT 'xxx', 'Plan', 'Capital', 96875 UNION ALL
SELECT 'xxx', 'Plan', 'Expense', 40625 UNION ALL
SELECT 'xxx', 'Actuals', 'Capital', 229949 UNION ALL
SELECT 'xxx', 'Actuals', 'Expense', 2848 UNION ALL
SELECT 'yyy', 'Actuals', 'Expense', 0 

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I added a matrix with row groups for WBSNumbers and Account and a column group for Table.

I added a new column outside the column group with the expression stated above

I added an extra row for the headers but this was not really required - just to make it match the expected output more closely.

The final design looks like this.

[image]

The final output looked like this...

[image]

Other than the fact that the sample data does not match the supplied expected output for ABS yyyy this works as expected.

Comment: I tried this earlier and now too, i am getting #Error

Comment: try adding a new column outside the column group with just one part of the expression and check what it returns. (e.g. `=SUM(IIF(Fields!Table.Value = "Plan", Fields!Total.Value,0))` ) If this returns an error then check the output and error windows for more clues. Also check datatypes and spellings (case sensitive)

Comment: Alan, below is the warning

[rsAggregateOfMixedDataTypes] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox58.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses an aggregate function on data of varying data types.  Aggregate functions other than First, Last, Previous, Count, and CountDistinct can only aggregate data of a single data type.

I have changed the total column to number format, that did not help.

Used only =SUM(IIF(Fields!Total.Value = "Plan", Fields!Total.Value),0)) and this got error too.

The column is added as "Outside Group - Right"

Comment: =(IIF(Fields!Table.Value = "Plan", SUM(Fields!Total.Value),0))-(IIF(Fields!Table.Value = "Actuals", SUM(Fields!Total.Value),0))

This is not throwing error, but adding values instead of subtracting

Comment: `" =SUM(IIF(Fields!Total.Value = "Plan", Fields!Total.Value),0)) and this got error too "` This is incorrect, you should be comparing the `Table` field to `"Plan"` not the `Total` field. As for your second comment, you'll need to edit your question and show some sample data from the DATASET and expected results. I Have tested my answer and it works as expected.

Comment: Sorry, i actually used 'Table', but wrongly stated as 'Field' in my comment. I am not able to upload an example file (may be i am overlooking), but i have included screenshot of the Matrix table and the current Output.

The sample data is like below
WBS | Table | Account | Total
xxx | Plan | Capital | 97875
xxx | Plan | Expense | 40625
xxx | Actuals | Capital | 229949
xxx | Actuals | Expense | 2848
yyy | Actuals | Expense | 0

Comment: You can't share files directly, but you should edit your question with the sample data rather than posting in a comment as it's difficult to understand. You can post a script to generate the table and data if you like, type it by hand like you have in the comment but formatted clearly or do it in excel and post a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I have updated the original question and added a screenshot with expected output and current output. Hope that helps.

Comment: I've just built the report and it works fine, answer updated above. Please try to recreate using my simple example then go back to your report and see what's different.

Comment: Could the issue due to Visual Studio version? I am using Visual Studio Professional 2015 (Update 3) . I have the same matrix table as you and the same expression, but still getting the error.

Comment: Highly unlikely that the problem is VS. Can you create a new report, and recreate my sample report, including the sample dataset and make sure that works.

Comment: It worked with your data set and report. Thank you for the efforts. I will check again what i am doing wrong.

Comment: No problem. I would suggest you start the report from scratch, keep it as simple as possible, keeping as close to the sample report as you can. Check things like datatypes, case sensitivity and so on. You'll probably find it's something really simple that fixes it.

Comment: Thank you Alan for your valuable suggestions. I started it from scratch and i got the error again. I tweaked my query again and it worked, the key was changing the Totals column type to float as you did in your query. That did the trick!!!

Comment: I guess the datatype was not numeric, glad you got it sorted anyway :)